# JQuery find table row where Object == Table Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have seen kinda similar problems but nothing that seems to work for me.

I have an `AJAX`call in my JQuery which returns a list of Group Names, I then, for each object in the list, need to look through the table for a match and change the class of one of the cells in the row. So basically:

1. AJAX returns JSon result with a `List<string>` with Group Names.
2. Look for the td where `List object == TD.Text()`.
3. Change a class in the table row (I know how to do this so not to important)

**Jquery**

```
$("#UserGridView_DXMainTable .dxgv").click(function () {
            //Get data to send to controller
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetUserGroups", "Home")',
                    data: { 'userLogin': insertText },
                    type: "post",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                            data.GroupNames.each(function () { <== Is this correct?
                             <====== I cannot seem to find a working solution for here.
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetUserGroups(string userLogin)
        {
            if (userLogin != null)
            {
                Manager manager = new Manager();
                var details = manager.GetUserData(userLogin);
                var userGroupsID = details.GroupsId;
                List<string> GroupNames = new List<string>();
                for(var i = 0; i < userGroupsID.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var Gdetails = manager.GetGroupData(userGroupsID[i]);
                    var GName = Gdetails.Name;
                    GroupNames.Add(GName);
                }

            return Json(new { GroupNames = GroupNames }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

        }

        return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

I'm open to all suggestions, let me know if you want to know anything else.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

Example of returned data:

data.GroupNames = ["Default", "Normal User", "Manager" etc..]

Comment: data.GroupNames is it empty or undefined? Did u print the result or sure that you have data in result

Comment: data.GroupNames is populated in the controller and is returning a list of string objects @Akki619

Comment: The problem is that I cannot look through a table and find the matching table row @Akki619

Comment: can you show us the table structure and the object structure ?

Comment: @hjardine I can see that. my question was did you print it in ajax success method. show us the response data.

Comment: The table is a devexpress table so it wouldn't be of much help to put it in here but I can adapt generic code to work for a devexpress table, data.GroupNames will return a list of names of groups e.g Default, Generic, Normal Users etc. @JoelAlmeida

Comment: Please see 'EDIT:' , Hope this clears it up @Akki619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, `GroupNames` is an array of text and you are looking to see if this text matches any text in the td's? If then try this.

```
    $tds = $('td');
    $.each(data.GroupNames, function (index, val) {
        console.log(val + ' ' + index);
        $tds.each(function(){
            if($(this).text() === val){
                console.log('found');
            }
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/no97jgm5/)

The algorithm can be optimized by removing a td everytime it matches (unless a td can match multiple GroupNames)

Comment: how would I optimize this as it can take a very log time sometimes (td can only match one GroupNames), thanks

Comment: @hjardine you'll have to break the each loop after you find the val by adding **return false;** right after **console.log('found');** then since a **td** can only match one **GroupName** you'll have to find a way to remove that **td** from your **tds** list so you don't have to check it over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please change in controller from

return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet); --> return Json(new { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);